# Dependencies on unix based system

Tags: unix, dependencies, libraries, package-managers

For installing software, each 'platform' has its own package manager : brew, apt, pip, Bundle, etc ...

But for plain old compiled project, is there any standard for declaring dependencies in an actionable way, amenable go `(brew,apt,yum..) install` all of them?

As of now, I

- look at whatever `./configure` complains about,
- brew install
- add to the -L path etc...

This is quite tedious and ineffective, but I dont know any better way.

Is there such a standard mechanism I missed for plain old source code ?

Comment: Because each platform and package manager is different, you pretty much have to play by the local rules — do as the primary package manager does — or put the onus onto the people installing your package, clearly identifying the pre-requisites and where they can be satisfied.

Comment: The managers I know of are definitely specific, hence my question. But the need for specific library is across the board. So make etc.. have not connected with the existence of such package managers yet, to allow for simple dependency management ?